# Android - How to detect the final Activity in the stack

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, back-stack, android-task

I use the code below to check the final `Fragment` in an `Activity` to pop a dialog

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if there is only one fragment
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
                DlgUniversalError.shallIQuit(this, getApplicationContext()
                        .getResources().getString(R.string.doYouWantToQuit),
                        getSupportFragmentManager());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

---

Now suppose i have a set of `Activity`s. How can I perform the same for an `Activity` whether the `Activity` is the last in the stack, and pop a quit dialog ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but it makes me think of this: [Activity#isTaskRoot()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot%28%29)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have Activities 1,2,3 ... and their flow is:

```
Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> ... and so on
```

The only choice you really have is that in your `Activity 1`, override the `onBackPressed()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    /* Call the Quit Dialog here. If user presses YES,
     * call super.onBackPressed(), else if user presses NO,
     * do nothing. */

}
```

The `Fragment` backstack is local to the application, whereas the `Activity` backstack is local to a [**task**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). Now there are a couple of ways to check the status of the current task's `Activity` backstack:

**1.** Say your `Activity` flow is

```
A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> A1 ...
```

It is possible to ensure that `Activity 1` always starts with an empty backstack. Each time you start `Activity 1` with [`startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), call it with the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

**2.** There is a method called [isTaskRoot()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot%28%29) that lets you know if an `Activity` is the first `Activity` in that task, i.e. the last `Activity` on that task's backstack. This looks promising.

**3.** Turns out there is one more way to determine if an `Activity` is the last one on the backstack:

```
    ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);

    if(taskList.get(0).numActivities == 1 && taskList.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getName())) {
        /* do whatever you want e.g. super.onBackPressed() etc. */
    }
```

For this, add `android.permission.GET_TASKS` permission to your manifest.

So there ... :)

Comment: Yes... thats correct .... How about: `Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 1->  Activity 3`

Comment: I used a different navigation design as u suggested in your first comment .... thats a good user pattern compared to my question ..... Thanks for the info !

Comment: `getRunningTasks` is deprecated now.